# Mostrar el resultado de 2 procedimientos almacenados en una vista

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, razor, controller

Hola a todos soy nuevo en el mundo de desarrollo  con asp.net, quiero mostar el resultado de 2 procedures en una sola vista.

```
public List<prodUnidad> Detalle_Producto(string codigo)
    {
        List<prodUnidad> detalleProducto = new List<prodUnidad>();
        //list detProdUnidad = new list();

        using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new 
SqlDataAdapter("SP_SELECT_PRODUCTO_UNID", CCNN))
        {

            adap.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CO_PRODUCTO", codigo));


            adap.Fill(ds);
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                prodUnidad dprd = new prodUnidad();


                dprd.CO_PRODUCTO = Convert.ToString(row["CO_PRODUCTO"]);
                dprd.NN_NOMBRE = Convert.ToString(row["NN_NOMBRE"]);
                dprd.VA_PRECIO = Convert.ToDecimal(row["VA_PRECIO"]);
                if (!(row["VA_PRECIO_OFERTA"] is DBNull))
                {
                    dprd.VA_PRECIO_OFERTA = Convert.ToDecimal(row["VA_PRECIO_OFERTA"]);
                }
                if (!(row["VA_PRECIO_PUNTO"] is DBNull))
                {
                    dprd.VA_PRECIO_PUNTO = Convert.ToDecimal(row["VA_PRECIO_PUNTO"]);
                }
                dprd.CO_PRODUCTO_IMAGEN = Convert.ToString(row["CO_PRODUCTO_IMAGEN"]);
                dprd.FILE_IMG = Convert.ToString(row["FILE_IMG"]);
                dprd.NN_CATEGORIA = Convert.ToString(row["NN_CATEGORIA"]);
                dprd.DE_DESCRIPCION = Convert.ToString(row["DE_DESCRIPCION"]);

                detalleProducto.Add(dprd);

            }


        }
        return detalleProducto;

    }
}
```

el otro resultado de la ejecución[on es

```
        public List<ListProduct> Detalle_Producto_Modelo(string codigo)
    {
        List<ListProduct> detProdModel = new List<ListProduct>();
        //list detProdModel = new list();

        using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_SELECT_PRODUCTO_UNID_MODEL", CCNN))
        {
            //SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_SELECT_PRODUCTO", CCNN);
            adap.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CO_PRODUCTO", codigo));


            adap.Fill(ds);
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                ListProduct lprd = new ListProduct();

                lprd.CO_PRODUCTO = Convert.ToString(row["CO_PRODUCTO"]);
                lprd.NN_NOMBRE = Convert.ToString(row["NN_NOMBRE"]);
                lprd.VA_PRECIO = Convert.ToDecimal(row["VA_PRECIO"]);
                if (!(row["VA_PRECIO_OFERTA"] is DBNull))
                {
                    lprd.VA_PRECIO_OFERTA = Convert.ToDecimal(row["VA_PRECIO_OFERTA"]);
                }
                if (!(row["VA_PRECIO_PUNTO"] is DBNull))
                {
                    lprd.VA_PRECIO_PUNTO = Convert.ToDecimal(row["VA_PRECIO_PUNTO"]);
                }
                lprd.CO_PRODUCTO_IMAGEN = Convert.ToString(row["CO_PRODUCTO_IMAGEN"]);
                lprd.FILE_IMG = Convert.ToString(row["FILE_IMG"]);
                lprd.NN_CATEGORIA = Convert.ToString(row["NN_CATEGORIA"]);


                detProdModel.Add(lprd);

            }

        }
        return detProdModel;

    }

}
```

obviamente tengo 2 modelos para  cada una de los métodos:

```
{
public class ListProduct
{
    public string NN_NOMBRE { get; set; }
    public string CO_PRODUCTO { get; set; }
    public string CO_PRODUCTO_IMAGEN { get; set; }
    public decimal? VA_PRECIO { get; set; }
    public decimal? VA_PRECIO_OFERTA { get; set; }
    public decimal? VA_PRECIO_PUNTO { get; set; }
    public string FILE_IMG { get; set; }
    public string NN_CATEGORIA { get; set; }
    public string DE_DESCRIPCION { get; set; }
    public string NN_MARCA { get; set; }
    public string DE_TALLA { get; set; }
}
public class prodUnidad
{
    public string NN_NOMBRE { get; set; }
    public string CO_PRODUCTO { get; set; }
    public string CO_PRODUCTO_IMAGEN { get; set; }
    public decimal? VA_PRECIO { get; set; }
    public decimal? VA_PRECIO_OFERTA { get; set; }
    public decimal? VA_PRECIO_PUNTO { get; set; }
    public string FILE_IMG { get; set; }
    public string NN_CATEGORIA { get; set; }
    public string DE_DESCRIPCION { get; set; }
    public string NN_MARCA { get; set; }
    public string DE_TALLA { get; set; }
}
}
```

para cada una de ellas,

que debería hacer para mostrar el resultado de los 2 procedures en la vista, y como debería de hacerlo, pro favor su apoyo.

Comment: Hola!, De que forma lo queres mostrar? en tablas?

Comment: un procedimiento devuelve el detalle de un producto y el otro devuelve un lista  de productos   que tienen un vinculo en el producto detalle mostrado.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias definir una clase que agrupe las dos clases permitiendo definir un unico model para la view

Algo como ser

```
public class xxModel
   public List<ListProduct> ListProduct {get; set;}
   public List<prodUnidad> prodUnidad{get; set;}
}
```

lo usarias

```
xxModel model = new xxModel();
model.ListProduct = obj.Detalle_Producto_Modelo(codigo);
model.prodUnidad = obj.Detalle_Producto(codigo);

return View(model),
```

ese modelo es el usara la view

Comment: Agradezco por tu respuesta, lo hice tal como sugieres, sin embargo tengo inconvenientes para mostrar la data en el razor,  importo una colección del nemespace del modelo y  recorro  con un foreach( var item in Model.xxxxx):

Comment: no puedo referenciar a las variables tipo listas creadas en el modelo... por favor espero sus sugerencias

Comment: no puedes referenciarlas desde donde? desde la view? recuerda que ese modelo lo defines en el proyecto mvc y lo defines como using en la cshtml